# Keep inactive nav-tab displayed when input inside of it has focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I currentely working on a project with reactjs,and i would like to display error messages one by one using  link tag, this link may refer to a div, p, input, button whatever html element.

click the link, the appropriate html element should be focused and displayed.

the problem now,  is sometimes the target element is inside a hidden tab or div, and i can't focus it

for example inside an inactive tab, Is there any chance that I can make it active, then focus the element ?

here is a simple example :

```js
 

function openCity(cityName) { 
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}

const findIt = () => {  
  document
    .getElementById("target")
    .focus(); 
};
```

```css
.w3-container {
  margin-top:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  }
 
 .w3-container:after,.w3-container:before {
   content:"";
   display:table;
   clear:both
 }
 
 .w3-bar .w3-bar-item{
   padding:8px 16px;
   float:left;
   width:auto;
   border:none;
   display:block;
   outline:0
} 

.w3-black{ 
  color:#fff!important;
  background-color:#000!important 
}

.w3-button{
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
      <h2> 3 Tabs below :</h2> 
    </div>

    <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">
        London
      </button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">
        Paris
      </button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">
        Tokyo
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <input value="im ere ry o ind" id="target" />
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
      <h2>Tokyo</h2>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
     <br /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="findIt()">click to focus input inside PARIS tab</button>
```

so it works only if Paris is active

Answer (score 1):

Alright so, this is the question I solved- I have made it so are able to use the input field in the Paris tab, even when the tab is not selected.

I would never recommend using display:none in css. It hides the element completely, and javascript requires every bit of scaffolding it can get in order to do its job correctly. Instead, you can create a class that visually hides the content, but keeps it rendered in code space. In this case, I created a css class that will hide all content in the div it is assigned to. This makes it so that the content can still be accessed by Javascript's selectors, but doesn't appear unless the class is removed. In the javascript file, all I a really doing is removing and adding the class to elements, the same way you used display:none.

For further reading, I would recommend reading the following topic on css-tricks: 
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/is-display-none-the-right-way-to-hide-an-element/

```js
function openCity(cityName) { 
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].classList.add("hidden-visually");
    }
  document.getElementById(cityName).classList.remove("hidden-visually");
}

const findIt = () => {  
  document
    .getElementById("target")
    .focus(); 
};
```

```css
.hidden-visually{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

.w3-container {
  margin-top:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  }
 
 .w3-container:after,.w3-container:before {
   content:"";
   display:table;
   clear:both
 }
 
 .w3-bar .w3-bar-item{
   padding:8px 16px;
   float:left;
   width:auto;
   border:none;
   display:block;
   outline:0
} 

.w3-black{ 
  color:#fff!important;
  background-color:#000!important 
}

.w3-button{
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-container">
      <h2> 3 Tabs below :</h2> 
    </div>

    <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('London')">
        London
      </button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Paris')">
        Paris
      </button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">
        Tokyo
      </button>
    </div>
    


    <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city hidden-visually">
      <h2>Paris</h2>
      <input value="im ere ry o ind" id="target"/>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city hidden-visually">
      <h2>Tokyo</h2>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
     <br /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="findIt()">click to focus input inside PARIS tab</button>
```

Comment: i test it but it doesn't work. The target is to focus the input inside Paris tab onClick the button when London or Tokyo were selecetd ( active ).  the css enhancement is good

Comment: Have you tried running the code snippet I posted in my response? That was the functionality I attempted to create with it, and it seems to work from my testing.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't, what i'm expected is :
1- click London or Tokyo tab (that's important);
2- click the button "click to focus input inside PARIS tab";
after that the input inside Paris tab should be appeared

i hop i am clear

Comment: Hi @Malhar
i've just add `openCity("Paris")` inside findIt() function and it works as expected